# How to add a new command to the toolbar

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I am following Scott Hanselman's guide on how to add parallel build to my VS from here: ( I am using VS 2012) 
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HackParallelMSBuildsFromWithinTheVisualStudioIDE.aspx

So first I added MSBuild to my external tools (hopefully correctly!):
[image]

Then I went to commands section on Toolbar, which is where I can't follow his guides, mine looks like this:

[image]

So where and how can I find the `MSBuild` now?

Answer (score 0):

In the **Add Command** dialog scroll down the **Categories** list box to the **Tools** and then select the **External Command 4**:

[image]